# How chose encoding for coffeescript to JS?

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, coffeescript, phpstorm

I'm using watcher of PHPStorm to compile coffeescript in JS.

I need compilation uses a specific encoding (not UTF-8), exemple: ISO-XXXX.

How can I specify encoding to compilator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript compiler doesn't have cmd options for encoding. As far as I can see, it always reads files as UTF-8 and writes them accordingly